# Can GCP IAM can be used to provide access control on users of my business application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, abac, google-iam

I'm investigating different types of authorisation solutions that would provide ABAC style access control. I was wondering if GCP IAM can be used for that purpose, to provide custom business application resource access control?

Answer (score 1):

GCP IAM focuses on [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) for its infrastructure. If you want to apply the same to content, data, services, and apps running on top of GCP, you'll need an externalized authorization framework e.g. AuthZForce or Axiomatics [Policy Server](https://www.axiomatics.com) that use ALFA/XACML to implement ABAC policies

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at those, axiomatics is playing hard to get though, you have to sign NDA to get documentation. Did you have a chance to work with Open Policy Agent?

Comment: I know of OPA and it is great at infrastructure (for instance they have a K8 plugin). Try AuthZForce instead (open source) if Axiomatics (commercial) is not an option